# Mongodb find method always return all elements of the documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have `student` collection

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "Student",
  tasks: [{ month: 1, year: 2018 }]
}
```

I need a query which would return only array of tasks:

```
db.collection('students').find(
  {
    'tasks.month': 1,
    'tasks.year': 2018
  },
  {
    'tasks.$' : 1
  }
).toArray((err, res) => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

This return all the documents with all field, including `name` and so on ...

Comment: `db.collection('students').find(
  {
    'tasks.month': 1,
    'tasks.year': 2018
  },
  {
    'tasks' : 1
  }
)` try this

Comment: Thanks .. but returns the same result

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZYg5sL6Tkv8 ??? remove `.toArray()` and use callback directly

Comment: @anthony you should write this in the answer.

Comment: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 1):

The `find` would return a `cursor`. Based on the `cursor` [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html) if you want to `project` then you can simply do:

`.project({'tasks' : 1})`

before your `.toArray` ... so you end up with:

```
var result = db.collection('students').find({
  'tasks.month': 1,
  'tasks.year': 2018
}).project({
  'tasks': 1
}).toArray((err, res) => {
  console.log(res)
})
```